# Replace string 'a , b,c' to 'a, b, c' using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I convert this string

```
a   ,  b,c,d , e,  f
```

to:

```
a, b, c, d, e, f
```

I'm trying this regex but it doesn't do what I expected:

```
str.replace(/(\w)|(?:[ \t]+),(\w)|(?:[ \t]+)/g, "$1, $2")
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may use it this way:

```js
var str = 'a   ,  b,c,d , e,  f';
console.log( str.replace(/\s*,\s*/g, ', ') );
//=> a, b, c, d, e, f
```

Here pattern `\s*,\s*` searches for a comma surrounded with 0 or more whitespaces on either side and we replace it with `,`  to get our desired output.

Answer (score 5):

Regular expressions are not the most maintainable code. You can achieve this by converting the string to an array, removing the extra whitespace, and then converting it back to a string with the desired separators.

It will probably be slightly slower, but that is unlikely to have noticable impact, and it will result in easier to read code:

```js
const result = "a   ,  b,c,d , e,  f"
  .split(",")
  .map(char => char.trim())
  .join(", ");
  
console.log(result);
```